# oracle PL/SQL: sort order by issue

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [oracle PL/SQL: sort rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798939/oracle-pl-sql-sort-rows)

I run this query:

```
 Select a.product, sum(
     case 
       when b.id=1 then round(c.sales,3)
       else 0 
     end) as Q1_2008,
 sum(
     case 
         when b.id=2 then round(c.sales,3) 
         else 0 
     end) as Q2_2008,
 sum(
     case
         when b.id=3 then round(c.sales,3) 
         else 0
     end) as Q3_2008
 from products a, quarters b, sales c
 where 
    a.id=c.PRODUCT_ID and 
    b.id=c.QUARTER_ID 
 group by a.product
 order by product
```

But my Product column is not in order.

### PRODUCT

PROD_1
PROD_10
PROD_2
PROD_3
PROD_4
PROD_5
PROD_6
PROD_7
PROD_8
PROD_9

PROD_10 is the second row when it should be at the end. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of an "order by" statement that does what you want:

```
order by cast(substr(product, 5, 100) as int)
```

Answer (score 5):

That is in order.  Order by for numbers and strings are different.

11 is less than 2 in a string, so produect_10 is placed before your product_2.  If you wish to sort by a number in a string, you must pull that number out and sort on it by itself as a number.

Answer (score 1):

use substr to pick out the numeric portion of the string.

use to_number to turn it into a number

sort by that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must use strings (given this same question has been asked a few minutes ago), then you may have to go some byzantine split/convert route. i.e. take the substring before _, chuck it away, convert remaining part to integer, order by that. I wouldn't want to vouch for it being a sustainable solution though.

Comment: Jeff, I have had to do this many times, there are no problems doing this in your apps.

Answer (score 0):

What Limey said is correct. If you want to order the names correctly then either rename the strings so that they are padded by 0s...for example PROD_01, PROD_01, PROD_02, PROD_03, PROD_10. this way all will be in order.

else split, to_number and then Order the number part of the product.(this will only work in case you have common string as prefix as the product name)